# Given SAML SP metadata, is it possible to use the OneLogin API to create an app?

Tags: api, onelogin

I have an application that I have turned into a SAML Service Provider (that is, an application that receives a SAMLResponse in order to authorize a user). Currently, when I want to use OneLogin as an Identity Provider (that is, a service that authenticates that a user is who they say they are), I have to manually configure a SAML test connector - a process which is rather fraught with perils for the user configuring the service.

I can, with minimal work, generate an SP metadata for the service that I have created. I know that all of OneLogin's SAML apps generate an IdP metadata to be used to configure SAML Services.

Can I use the SP metadata that I generate to create an app in OneLogin in order to get the IdP metadata so that my Service can authorize users with OneLogin? Is this what OneLogin's "Custom Connectors" are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at this time at least, you can't.

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom SAML SP app you need to use at OneLogin side a "SAML Test connector", where register  SP metadata on the "configuration" tab and get the IdP metadata to be registered on the SP app. That is a simple process.

Currently that functionality is only available at the OneLogin platform, but soon will be avaibale via API.

Comment: Thanks @smartin! Currently I'm using custom connectors for testing my app, but I don't want my users to have to create them. While O.L. has streamlined the process a lot, I feel like I would still rather have users do minimal configuration to have our apps interoperate.         
  
I see you've answered a lot of questions on O.L (about 50 at time of writing). Do you work with them? If yes, could you update this answer when O.L. has this functionality? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I will :)